# Jenkins Swarm Slave

Tags: docker, jenkins, docker-swarm

I have a question concerning Jenkins Build Server. When Jenkins slaves are tasked with building or compiling do the slaves need the necessary software installed on them? For example, if I am using an IAR ARM compiler do I need this software installed on the slave node? or just on the master?

I am tasked with making a Jenkins Build environment for many developers and for scalability I am using Docker Swarm.

Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, your slaves will need all the build tools you require installed on them.  Generally speaking, Jenkins doesn't know how to install software on your slaves, and Jenkins uses the toolchain on the slave to run builds.